# DotNetNuke 4.9.2 WebUpload Control Null Exception

Tags: asp.net, controls, dotnetnuke

Trying to use the dnn webupload control in a dnn 4.9.2 module. I am using this in the settings.aspx of my module. When I load the page I get a null exception on this line in the page_init:

```
Me.ModuleConfiguration.ModuleTitle = Services.Localization.Localization.GetString("UploadType" & FileType.ToString, Me.LocalResourceFile)
```

I tried to set the FileType, which is what is null but it is read only. I would static the title, but I don't want to change core code, for upgrade reasons.

Any suggestions?

Comment: So you ae setting the module title by getting the file type of the upload control?  little confused by what you are doing - can you show more code here?

Comment: No I could care less about the title, that is part of the dnn core code. When I add the control to my form and debug, it breaks at that line in the webupload control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The control expects a parameter in the querystring. I decided to put my code in the edit module page instead of the settings page as the edit page does not user an AjaxUpdate panel which was causing issues with the asp.net fileupload control. So I scrapped the webupload control and used that.